# Calculating an *integer* binomial coefficient in R

Tags: r, integer, binomial-coefficients

The number of ways of choosing *k* objects from *n*, i.e. the binomial coefficient *n!/(k!(n-k)!)*, is an integer when *n* and *k* are integers. How can I calculate this guaranteeing that the result is both correct and of integer type? The `choose` function returns a double even with integer arguments:

```
> typeof(choose(4L, 2L))  
[1] "double"
```

as does manual calculation, e.g. *n*-choose-2 = *n(n-1)/2*

```
typeof((4L * (4L - 1L)) / 2L)
[1] "double"
```

Of course I can coerce to an integer with `as.integer()` but I'm nervous about machine precision:

```
> as.integer(3.999999999999999)
[1] 3
> as.integer(3.9999999999999999)
[1] 4
```

`round()` (with the default `digits=0`) rounds to the nearest integer, but returns a value of double type. If I could be certain that supplying an integer stored in double format to `as.integer(round(...))` is guaranteed to round to the correct integer, never being tripped up by machine precision, then `as.integer(round(choose(n, k)))` would be acceptable. Is this the case? Or is there an alternative to `choose()` that will return an integer for integer arguments?

Comment: `typeof((4L * (4L - 1L)) %/% 2L)` will give you integer , if you choose to use `%/%` instead of `/` you will get integer

Comment: I'm not sure that it is what @ChrisW wants... because `5 %/% 2 = 2`

Comment: Indeed, I don't think that answers my question.

Comment: Since n!/(k!(n-k)!) will always return an integer if n and k are integers, there is no need to `round` it, just do `as.integer(choose(n, k))`. you only need rounding if your inputs are non-integers.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the VeryLargeIntegers package. The function is:

binom(n, k)

e.g. binom(1000,50) or even binom(10000000,50)

It's wise to learn how to make very large integers too cf: as.vli('1234567890123456789')

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/VeryLargeIntegers/versions/0.1.8/topics/06.%20Binomial%20coefficients

The package is not completely bug-free, and larger computations will take a while.

Dr Jo.

Answer (score 0):

Do not worry about the conversion, the machine precision will not be a problem. L after the integer is definitely not a double, [R] has a weird syntax, it is definitely not a long value and cannot have a decimal point.